# Maintaining data history in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am working on mapping and characterizing watercourses. I use the shapefile in QGIS (version 3.28.8 - Firenze) to represent the water body and to insert data obtained in the field. However, I have a problem: as I have to return to the same points on different dates, the conditions always change. I would like to know how I can, in QGIS, describe these changes in the database, but without losing the previous description, that is, maintaining a history. I know it's not correct, but what I've been doing is inserting new columns to record the new data, but the table is huge... I read something about "space-time cubes", but I confess that I don't know how to use this technology. Do you have suggestions to resolve what I reported?

Comment: I think the usual way would be to use a related table with a 1-n relationship to store each visit with the visit date.

Comment: Maybe you could read this : https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#introducing-1-n-relations and update your question

Comment: Space time cubes is a style, a way of visualizing data, not of organizing data. See here for the concept: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/space-time-pattern-mining/learnmorecreatecube.htm For QGIS, there is a Plugin: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/space_time_cube/ See also here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ibbs7u-iawE

Comment: Excellent. I will study the QGIS text and look for other analogues to the '1-N relations' theme. I will try to apply the technique and, as soon as I get an answer, I will return here. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: You could import your shapefile into a [Kart](https://kartproject.org/) project to provide version control, similar to git. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7ETwmMlUtY for a recent presentation.

Comment: Do you update data over time and usually refer to the most up to date version, or are you regularly querying the data at different points in time?

Comment: Mike T, I will watch the recommended video. Thanks.

Comment: Hamish, I consult the data at different times. Firstly, I need to know the most current data, but it is also interesting for the work carried out to know the history of the actions that occurred on the mapped water entity. For example, suppose I have mapped and characterized a spring and entered its data into QGIS. If I need to write a document about that spring, I will write the current conditions, however, to improve, I can mention that it was in a natural state during the first inspection, but that it had been degraded during the second one. Is it confusing? Thanks for helping.

Comment: This is a common issue in database design (well beyond GIS). Based on your latest comment, you could either use two tables (current and history), or one table with a current record flag to show the latest record. Lots of info if you search.

Comment: Tom Brennan, as per your suggestion, I will look for information on what you commented. Let me just ask a question: two tables associated with the same shapefile or in another way? Thanks for your response.

Comment: I wouldn't use a shapefile in the first place - it's a legacy format! Assuming the points don't move over time, I would probably store the current data with the geometry, and a unique ID. I would then have a history table with no geometry, but with the history records, plus the ID to link it back to the first table. You could do all this in a single GeoPackage if there's not huge amounts of data. If there's a lot of data, then you might need to look at an actual database (PostGIS for example).

Comment: Tom Brennan and other gentlemen, this is excellent! I will do some research and some tests, comparing the proposed techniques. As soon as I get a response I will return here to explain what I did. I thank everyone immensely.